# Javascripts not loading in IE10 and 11 in my HTML5 file

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Here is my HTML5 file code. This works on all of the browsers on Mac and PC but IE 10 and IE 11 where none of my javascript loads into the file. I added the full site URL in the links to see if that would work and still nothing.  I am not an expert with IE stuff (since I really do not like it) so a little lost on this. Would anyone have a solution or suggestion? Thanks so much.

Here is the beginning of my HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <!--====== USEFULL META ======-->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="restaurant, pizza, burger, business, house, online, sports, bar" />
    <meta name="author" content="BDEXPERT" />

<!--====== TITLE TAG ======-->
    <title>Pitcher House Upper Deck</title>
<!--====== FAVICON ICON =======-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="img/favicon.png" />

<!--====== STYLESHEETS ======-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/pogo-slider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/datepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/timepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/magnific-popup.css">
<link href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://pitcherhouse.com/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--====== MAIN STYLESHEETS ======-->
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="//oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->          
</head>

And here is the bottom of my file where I call in all of the javascript.


<!--====== SCRIPTS JS ======-->
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--====== PLUGINS JS ======-->
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/vendor/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/vendor/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/jquery.pogo-slider.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/stellar.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/timepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>

<!--===== ACTIVE JS=====-->
<script src="http://pitcherhouse.com/js/main.js"></script>
```

Site URL is http://pitcherhouse.com

Comment: Scripts seem to load fine, but there's an error in main.js in line 159, a double definition of `freeDrag` property of an object. Disable the cache and reload the page on your IE ...

Comment: HOLY COW!!!  That worked.  THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!! What an eagle eye you have.

Comment: No eagle eyes, just the dev console = ).

Comment: dev console... what a good idea.  DUH on my part but thank you so much for your time.  I REALLY appreciate it.  Have a wonderful day or evening depending on where you are.